# c++ char pointer shallow copy to change value

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    char* str = "Hello";
    char* str2 = str;
    str2[0] = 'M';
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

// prints still "Hello" instead of "Mellow"
```

Is there anyway to make str change by changing str2?

Comment: Why would it print `Mellow`?

Comment: `"Hello"` is a `const char [6]`. Not a good thing to try and write to..

Comment: `char* str2 = str;` Doesn't _"copy"_ anything,  and you're trying to change constant memory you don't actually have access to. It's _undefined behavior_.

Comment: If you want that kind of behavior you should be using `std::string`

Comment: A Standard compliant compiler will tell you not to do this by refusing to compile the program: https://godbolt.org/z/YbhGE9MWr This one is merely warning, but heed the warning.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure it does - it copies the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ does considers string literals to have type `char const[N]`. You assigning this value to a pointer to non-`const` `char`s is illegal.

You can initialize a fixed size array of non-const chars with a string literal though:

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "Hello"; // creates a char[6] containing the chars of the string literal
    char* str2 = str;
    str2[0] = 'M';
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: oh snap... I never thought that c++ would automatically convert char* -> const char []. No wonder the value never changes since it is immutable... Thanks!

Comment: @DannielLee "*c++ would automatically convert char\* -> const char []*" - no, it doesn't. `"Hello"` is not a `char*`, it is a `const char [6]` to begin with. In `char* str = "Hello";` you are trying to point a `char*` to a `const char[]` and that is not allowed since C++11, you have to use `const char*` instead.